# How to measure power of my device?

Tags: power

My device is working with ten 1 watt LEDs. How can I measure the power consumption of my devices?

Comment: Like I said on your first post - Go get a multimeter. Then we can talk.

Comment: If you don't have a multimeter which is the obvious way to measure the current then it's worth adding that to the question along with a circuit and details on the LED so someone can suggest how to calculate it instead of measure it.

Comment: @Arshid Really, are you an EE? I'm not an EE but I know it and now I'm wonder that why you don't know it! you can see it even in a simple physics book. please, at least, first google(search) your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power (P) is voltage (E) times current (I):

$$ P = IE $$

This works for any individual part, or an entire circuit.

If you wanted to measure the power used by your entire circuit, measure the current your power supply is supplying, and the voltage at its output, and multiply them.

If you also want to include losses in the power supply, then measure the input voltage and current.

If you want to measure the power of an individual LED, measure the voltage across it and the current through it.

Comment: Towards your second point, is that an accurate measurement? What if internally some sort of current transformer is used or voltage transformer? Does power in always equal power out?

Comment: @sherrellbc Yes, by the law of conservation of energy (power being energy per time).

Comment: Of course, I was thinking of it in the wrong way. Obviously the difference is going to be that which was used up in supply.